# Recursion code ambigious answer

Tags: c, recursion, reference

What is the return value of `f(p,p)` if the value of p is initialized to 5 before the
call? Note that the first parameter is passed by reference, whereas the second parameter is passed by value.

```
int f (int & x, int c )
{
    c = c − 1;
    if ( c == 0 ) return 1;
    x = x + 1;
    return f ( x, c ) * x;
}
```

(A) 3024
 (B) 6561
 (C) 55440
 (D) 161051

According to me its 3024 because we start with
`f(5,5)`
`f(6,4)*6`
`f(7,3)*7`
`f(8,2)*8`
`f(9,1)*9`
then `1`, and I am little bit confused about call by reference part `return f ( x, c ) * x`
will the value of x change after every call or it will remain constant?

Comment: `int f (int & x, int c )` is a syntax error in C. Are you using C++ ?

Comment: it was asked in a competitive exam for masters....i thinks its just a code in c

Comment: Maybe it was a trick question? C does not have "references"; only pointers.

Comment: The code is invalid in C. The code has unpredictable (unspecified) behavior in C++. In other words, none of the A-D answers apply.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that this is really C++ instead of C (so the reference declaration makes some sense), the result is unspecified (but not undefined behavior).

The problem is that in the expression `f(x,c) * x`, it's unspecified whether the program will evaluate the second `x` before or after calling `f(x,c)`.

Note that since this behavior is unspecified, you can't depend on it at all - changing compiler options could possibly change the order of evaluation.  In fact, it's technically permitted for the compiler to evaluate the expression using one ordering for some calls of `f()` while using the other order for other calls to `f()` (though I imagine this doesn't ever happen in practice).